# No me salen los iconos que tengo en mi items en el menu que he creado en mi ToolBar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

No me salen los iconos  que tengo en mi items en el menu que he creado i me sale el siguiente error que supongo que no me deja sacarlos a la visata, Salen en la parte derecha de el `Preview` pero cuando corro la app no sale solamente los 3 punticos y se encuentran adentro

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes hacer exactamente lo que te dice el error. En lugar de `android:showAsAction="..."` debes usar `app:showAsAction="..."`

Me cuentas si te funciona.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ya se me quito el error que me aparecia subrayado en rojo !!